# Proving equivalence of norms

Tags: linear-algebra

How does the eigendecomposition of a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$ help in proving the norm equivalence:
$$\|x\|_A\equiv \|Ax\|_2$$
where the $A$-norm is induced by the inner product, $\|x\|_A^2=\langle Ax,x\rangle$.

edit:
Btw, I've tried the C.S. inequality, but I don't how to proceed with the square-root expressions. The best I've had is  $\|x\|^2_A\leq k\|Ax\|$

Comment: Consider using \| x \| to get $\| x \|$ instead of || x || which gives $|| x ||$.

Comment: Anything to help :-)

Comment: Btw, I've tried the C.S. inequality, but I don't how to proceed with the square-root expressions. The best I've had is $\|x\|_A^2 \leq k\|x\|_2$

Comment: Add this to your original question. People might not see it down in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\lambda_{min}(A) \|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_A \leq \lambda_{max}(A) \|x\|_2$.  It is helpful to start with the case in which $A$ is diagonal.

---

For the new version of the question: define $\|x\|_* = \|Ax\|$.  Notably, we have 
$$
\|x\|_*^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle= \langle x,A^2 x \rangle\\
\|x\|_A^2 = \langle A^{1/2}x, A^{1/2}x \rangle= \langle x,A x \rangle
$$
With that in mind: if we make the substitution $y = A^{1/2}x$, then it suffices to show that for all $y$, we have
$$
\lambda_{min}(A^{1/2})\|x\|_A = \lambda_{min}(A^{1/2}) \|y\|_2 \leq\\ \|y\|_{A^{1/2}} = \|x\|_* = \|Ax\| \leq\\ \lambda_{max}(A^{1/2}) \|y\|_2 = \lambda_{max}(A^{1/2})\|x\|_A
$$

Comment: I realised a typo in the question. Does this still hold with the edited question? I think I arrived at getting an expression with the max/min eigenvalues at some point in my scratch work

Comment: That looks a bit bizarre.  Are you really sure that the second norm should be
$$
\|x\|_{*} = \|Ax\|_2?
$$
I mean the statement is true, but strange

Comment: Yup. The topic is Conjugate Gradient,
with $e_i=x-x_i$ and $Ax=b$, prove
$\|e_i\|_A\equiv \|Ax_i - b\|_2$

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I think that substitution trick is what I needed.